# How to set different DNS servers for specific domains

Tags: dns, dd-wrt

I am new to Flashrouters and I was wondering if it is possible to set up different DNS servers for specific domains:

**For instance**: 
if domain is *ebay.com* or *nasa.org* then use 8.8.8.8 (as the DNS server) 
for all other domains use 200.200.1.1. instead.

Is that possible with DD-WRT? If so, what are the implications ? Will it make my web surfing slower ?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  what have you tried already? What were your results?  The best bet (IMO) is to setup forwarders in the local DNS to forward unknown requests to Google (or wherever), and then always use the local DNS.

Comment: Hi Techie.

Thanks for your answer.

I want to watch on my Apple TV and other devices (Tablets, XBOX...) channels from different countries, so for some services I need different DNS (like Unblock us) to be able to watch, for others my ISP's DNS is the best option.

Does that make sense?

Cheers

Comment: How do you propose to do this? Do you have ssh access to your AppleTV?

Comment: [Conditional Forwarders](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730756.aspx)

Comment: I wouyld like to that on the DD-WRT, if possible, so all devices (ATV3 included) would work as I expect. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with DD-WRT but what you want to do should be possible if you're able to  install a recent version of BIND.  What you'll want to do is declare the router as "authoritative" for whichever zone is "special" and then declare a "stub" within the zone declaration.  The zone declaration should look something like:

```
zone example.com {
  type stub;
  masters { 8.8.8.8; };
  file "stub-example-com"
};
```

Note: in reading available documentation, there appears to be additional methods for doing this (I haven't tested them).  One site claims that you can use the "forwarders" command in place of "masters".

Recommend grabbing grabbing the docs from the ISC website[1] and reading up on stubs.  In any case, hope this helps.

[1] https://kb.isc.org/article/AA-01031